# Referencing a class instance stored in an array in another class

Tags: javascript, class, this

Apologies if the title makes no sense. I've got myself quite muddled up but I'll try to elaborate on the problem below.

I have three Javascript classes:

A js (contains class map)
B js (contains class mapObject)
C js (logic for map maker)

In Class C I create an instance of map which is a canvas with a grid layout.

Users can click on the map and using hotkeys add instances of mapObject.

Now I'm trying to display the mapObject icons and am completely confused as to how:

Map creation & MapObject creation code (C js):

```
 case 13: // Enter Key (Submit)
        unhighlightTools();
        currentMap.drawMap();
        if(currentFloor != null){
            currentFloor.hasFloor = true;
            if(currentFloor.tileName == "Guild"){
                createGuildObject(currentFloor.position.x,currentFloor.position.y,currentFloor);
            }
            console.log("Map object created at - X:"+currentFloor.position.x+" Y:"+currentFloor.position.y);
            createMapObject(currentFloor.position.x,currentFloor.position.y,currentFloor);
        }
        currentFloor = null;
        highlightTools();
        break;
}

// Create a Map Object and push it to the currentMap with its position.
function createMapObject(x,y,floor){
currentMap.objects.push(new MapObject(x,y,floor));
}

// Create a Guild Object (extension of Map Object) and push it to the currentMap with its position.
function createGuildObject(x,y,floor){
currentMap.objects.push(new Guild(x,y,floor));
}
```

Defining Map Icon in MapObject (b js)

```
class MapObject {
constructor(x,y,floor) {
    this.position = {x, y};
    this.icon = this.wallFloorIcons(floor);
 }

 wallFloorIcons(floor) {
    var self = this;
    self.img = new Image();

    self.name = <code that creates the name>
    self.name = 'wall-'+self.name+'.png';

    if(self.name == 'wall-.png'){
        self.img.src = "../images/mapSprites/floor.png";
    }else {
        self.img.src = "../images/mapSprites/"+self.name;
    }

    console.log(self.img);
    return self.img;
 }
```

And here is the bit that has me confused. Using the icon from the MapObject in the Map class  (a js):

```
fillMap(){
    var self = this;

    self.c.lineWidth = 1;
    self.c.strokeStyle = 'black';
    self.c.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)";

    for (var row = 0; row < self.boxes; row++) {
        for (var column = 0; column < self.boxes; column++) {
            var x = column * self.boxSize;
            var y = row * self.boxSize;

            self.c.beginPath();
            self.c.rect(x, y, self.boxSize, self.boxSize);
            self.c.stroke();
            self.c.closePath();

            for (var i=0; i<self.objects.length; i++) {
                var floor = self.objects[i];
                if (floor.position.x == column && floor.position.y == row) {  
                    if (self.objectsAtPosition({x:floor.position.x, y:floor.position.y}) != null) {
                        var j = self.objectsAtPosition({x:floor.position.x, y:floor.position.y});
                        console.log(j.icon);
                        this.c.drawImage(self.objectsAtPosition({x:floor.position.x, y:floor.position.y}).getIcon(),x,y, self.boxSize, self.boxSize);
                    }
                }     
            }
        }
    }
```

In the final if statement I am checking if there are any objects at my position using this code in a.js:

```
objectsAtPosition(position) {
    var objs = [];
    for (var o of this.objects) {
        if (o.position.x == position.x && o.position.y == position.y) {
            objs.push(o);
        }
    }
    return objs;
}
```

So to summarise...

I am creating an instance of one class, pushing it to an array in another class. Then getting stuck trying to get the icon from the instance of the first class from the second.

My console.log(j.icon) returns undefined, I can't seem to get any of the details out of my MapObject, however if I console.log(j) then I do see the MapObject in the console with all its details.

I am still new at this and I'm sure I'm making a right mess of it, so please go easy on me :p

Thanks!
Lemongrab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectsAtPosition()` is returning an array of objects, and arrays don't have an `icon` property. Maybe you want to iterate over `self.objectsAtPosition({x:floor.position.x, y:floor.position.y})`:

```
const mapObjects = self.objectsAtPosition({x:floor.position.x, y:floor.position.y})
for (const mapObject of mapObjects) {
    this.c.drawImage(mapObject.getIcon(), x, y, self.boxSize, self.boxSize);
}
```

A few other suggestions:

1. Instead of `{x:floor.position.x, y:floor.position.y}` you can just use `floor.position`.
2. `objectsAtPosition()` can be written more simply with `Array.filter()`: `return this.objects.filter(o => o.position.x == position.x && o.position.y == position.y)`
3. There's no need to do `var self = this` unless you want to be able to access that value of `this` inside an anonymous function inside your method.

Comment: Thank you very much. Feel embarrassed now, I was looking at the array instead of the object >.<.